# How to change the number of input fields in PHP based on a MySQL value?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, dynamic

I am working on a PHP webapp. I have a table which contains a value for number of cells.

Lets say cells=4.

What I need to have happen, is PHP creates input fields for the number of cells.

For example:

```
Cell #1: (input field)
Cell #2: (input field)
Cell #3: (input field)
Cell #4: (input field)
```

The key thing is here, as the numbers of cells changes, so need for the code to allow for that.

I have googled my butt off, can't find anything on how to do this. I understand that I can create a loop to create the number of input boxes, but how do I create the text to the left of the input field together with the input boxes?

Comment: It is your homework? Did you ever heard from loops? "for"?

Answer (score 0):

```
//create a regular query (this one is in PDO, but it is just an example. just use your own and put a count on the results

$query = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE equal = to_equal";
$query = $db->query($query);
$query ->execute();
$query_fetch= $query ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//count the amount of rows
$query_fetch_count= count($query_fetch);
//amount of rows is now 4 for example
```

create a for loop to create the input fields

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $query_fetch_count; $i++) { 
    echo "<input type='text'>"
}
```

> EDIT

```
//something like this I believe. Putting the $i variable in the label and the input so it is equal to each other
  //or use the $query_fetch if you want to use the data and not a number.

    for ($i = 0; $i < $query_fetch_count; $i++) { 
    echo "<label for=".$i.">$i</label>;
    echo "<input type='text' id='$i'>"
}
```

Comment: I understand that this would be used to create 4 input boxes.  But how would I get the text field to the side of the box to be labeled 1.2.3.4?

Comment: How do you mean labeled? Do you mean give it a ID?

Comment: So mySQL query will return one row of data.  It will contain a serial number, type of battery, number of cells.    What I need to do is then have the follow on form take the number of cells and create an input box for the number of cells.   So if SQL returns the # of battery cells as 4.  It would create a box for cell 1, then 2, then 3, then 4.   I know i can do that through a loop.  But im not sure how I can get the plain text to the left of it to also count so that the plain text renders Cell 1, Cell 2, Cell 3, Cell 4.

Comment: Hold on, let me edit that to better explain (accidently hit the enter button.)